# How to write DDL against SQL SE database programmatically?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I have an SDF database file. I'm looking forward to manage my database in C#. for example I want to drop a table or change a table schema.

How can I achieve this?

I insist achieving this using Entity Framework and DbContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cmd is a SqlCeCommand object (or IDbCommand object)

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery("DROP TABLE myTable;");

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery("ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD ...");
```

With Entity Framework, you can use the above SQL statements like this:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DROP TABLE myTable;");
```

Comment: Thanks erik, but what is "cmd" anyway ? How can I use this with Entity Framework DbContext ?

Comment: You di not mention EF initially.

Comment: I am a bit confused about the Question, because if you alter your schema. Your Context (if the Tables belong to the Context) isn't working anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
using System.IO;

...

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public static void CreateDatabase(string connectionString)
        {
            using (var engine = new SqlCeEngine(connectionString))
            {
                if (IsDatabaseExists(connectionString))
                    File.Delete(GetPathToDatabase(connectionString));
                engine.CreateDatabase();

                using (var conn = new  SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    var cmd = new SqlCeCommand(@"CREATE TABLE [Users](
                                        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
                                        [Username] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL
                                        CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([ID]))";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    cmd.CommandText = @"CREATE TABLE [UserAnswers](
                                        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                                        [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
                                        [Question] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
                                        [Answer] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
                                        CONSTRAINT [PK_UserAnswers] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([ID]))";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    cmd.CommandText = @"ALTER TABLE [UserAnswers] ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_UserAnswers_Users] FOREIGN KEY([UserID])
                                        REFERENCES [Users] ([ID])
                                        ON DELETE CASCADE";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to manage your Database from a Database Project in Visual Studio, am I right?
If so, you have to add a Database Project to your solution. But I really don't know if your Version is supported.

Comment: No danny, I want to write a library in C# using entity framework against my sdf file to manage my database schema. Just with Code